# I am stuck between post meta function to call unique id

Tags: post-meta

I have created a system on which on the front end it is possible for user to write a little suggestion below the post. It's separate from the comment system

The code I used is

```
<form method='POST' action="">
    <textarea name=posrav value="">Text here</textarea>
    <input type=submit value=submit>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['posrav'])) {
    if($_POST['posrav']!="") {
        $posrav=get_post_meta($post->ID,'pcom',true);
        $posrav=$_POST['posrav'];
        add_post_meta($post->ID,'pcom',$posrav);
    }
}

$arpos=get_post_meta($post->ID,'pcom',false);

foreach ($arpos as $arposv){
    echo $arposv . "Thumbup";
    echo "</br>";
}

?>
```

Now I have already seeing what other people are writing on this form but what I want is the thumb up and thumb down function on these meta lines so that people can vote up and vote down any suggestion. The problem I am facing is the post meta can be called by a unique key that is `pcom` in my case, but how will I am going to call and link vote up down function to post meta?

Comment: Please fix your title. You should also validate and sanitize your incoming `$_POST` (user?) input. In it's current state, I can just call `http://example.com?posrav=whatever` and vote automatically. One could also just hack your site.

Comment: Of-course I will be doing all the things, its in development initial phase right now

Comment: Again: Please fix the question title and make it more meaningful. "I am stuck between my coding" does not describe anything whatsoever.

Comment: -1 for not correcting post title, post title is misleading

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `update_post_meta` insted of `add_post_meta`

```
if(isset($_POST['posrav'])) {
    if($_POST['posrav']!="") {
        $posrav=get_post_meta($post->ID,'pcom',true);
        $posrav=$_POST['posrav'];
        update_post_meta($post->ID,'pcom',$posrav);
    }
}
```